# Get first and last element from Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I would like to know if there is any way to get the first and last value of a data grouped by date, using the Laravel eloquent.
I need the data to put on the TradingView candle chart, and it needs a specific formatting, as follows:

```
{
  t:'unix timestamps',
  v:'volumes',
  h:'higher prices',
  l:'lower prices',
  o:'open prices',
  c:'close prices'
}
```

My code is:

```
$trans = Transacoes::where('created_at', '>=', $end->subMinutes($minute))
        ->groupBy('t')
        ->orderBy('t', 'DESC')
        ->get([
            DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i") as t'),
            DB::raw('sum(amount) as "v"'),
            DB::raw('max(`price`) as h'),
            DB::raw('min(`price`) as l'),
            DB::raw('first(`price`) as o'),
            DB::raw('last(`price`) as c'),
        ])
        ->toArray();
```

I know the `first()` and `last()` functions do not exist for MySQL, but I wrote that way so it would be easier to understand what I'm trying to do.

My array is currently returning:

```
{
    "t": "2018-11-13 12:20", 
    "v" : "0.04536078", 
    "h" : "24249.98", 
    "l": "24249.97"
 }, 
 {...},
```

I needed to include the opening price and the closing price for each of the arrays, for example: in the minute corresponding to 12:20, there were 4 transactions, I need to know which was the first one and which was the last one at this minute and includes it in each element of the array with index "o" and "c"

Comment: Please add this in your post by editing

Comment: Also, how are you getting a JSON when you did a `toArray()` there?

Comment: No, JSON is as I get in my javascript, `toArray()` returns me an ordinary array.

Comment: Can you show a proper result(don't trim it) and the expected output?

Comment: https://brasilbitcoin.com.br/chart/history?symbol=BTC&resolution=30&from=1536858800&to=1536945260

Comment: Ok, edit your post and take 5-10 arrays from it and paste it in your post and show us what is the expected output you expect from them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = array_key_exists(0,$trans)?$trans[0]:"";
$last= array_key_exists(count($trans)-1,$trans)?$trans[count($trans)-1]:"";
```

I assume you have `$trans` as an array

Comment: my array is currently returning: `{"t": "2018-11-13 12:20", "v" : "0.04536078", "h" : "24249.98", "l": "24249.97"}, {...}`, I needed to include the opening price and the closing price for each of the arrays, for example: in the minute corresponding to 12:20, there were 4 transactions, I need to know which was the first one and which was the last one at this minute and includes it in each element of the array.